# Set Reporting services parameter value in subscription as current date

Tags: sql, reporting-services, parameters

In reporting services SQL server ,  when I created a subscription for a report with parameter as date time type, I don’t know how to set up value of the parameter as current date (wherever the subscription is running).

I tired Today(), Today, today, @ExecutionTime. But none of them worked for me. Only a specific date worked eg: “11/11/2010 00:00:00”.

I also tried to hide the parameter but the subscript still required to fill the parameter. For the "default value” textbox did not allow the value “Today()”, “Today”, etc.

Thanks in advance!

Helen

Comment: I can't believe no one has a good answer to this yet. It seems obvious that Microsoft should provide some sort of native variable like "@Today" which could be used in the subscription interface, similar to "@ReportName"

Answer (score 4):

You need `=` to make it an expressions

```
= Today()
```

Comment: This is misleading as it doesn't relate to the question, which asks about the issue when setting up a subscription on a report server. You can't use expressions when specifying parameter values when setting up a subscription.

Answer (score 4):

You can't put "=today()" in the text box prompt at runtime.  You have to setup the parameter's default value as "=today()" in visual studio.

Comment: Is there a way to do this without changing the parameter in Visual Studio? We have a wide range of users and not everyone want's today, some people want a week or a month and without some sort of today(), today()-7 functionality, I'm not seeing how to do this.

Answer (score 2):

Try Data Driven subscription and pass a SQL Statement to return the current date for the parameter value.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer. Check this [metaSO question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7656/how-do-i-write-a-good-answer-to-a-question) and [Jon Skeet: Coding Blog](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2009/02/17/answering-technical-questions-helpfully.aspx) on how to give a correct answer.

Comment: Is it possible to email result of a data-driven subscription? Only saw "Windows file Share" and "Null Delivery Provider" ...

Answer (score 1):

The following code worked on my case:

```
parameter1.Value = Date.Today()
```

Comment: This doesn't relate to setting up a subscription. This won't work

Answer (score 0):

I tried it as well but it did not work for the subscription.

Sorry I can not attach the screen shot in the post currently.

In Subscription screen shows:
Report Parameter Values
Specify the report parameter values to use with this subscription.
Date To = Today()

Regards,

Helen

Answer (score 0):

Actually I did that in visual studio and it worked well in preview (display the current date by default for the parameter and allow people to select other date) .

But for some reason, the subscription setting still asked me for the parameter value (as in the early post  "Report Parameter Values").

Answer (score 0):

On the report parameter configuration (on development time, not on the subscription creation), add a default value for the parameter. If you do, you will have a check box called "use default value" when creating the subscription

Answer (score 0):

If you want to default the report parameter to the current date in the short format, you can set the default value of the parameter to the expression:

=CDate(FormatDateTime(Now, DateFormat.ShortDate))